# GSP support in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, grails, eclipse-plugin, gsp

[The how-to](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2015/10/17/eclipse-mars-grails-3-1-with-gradle-groovy-and-gsp-support/) worked fine in `Neon` but failed miserably in `Oxygen`.

Hence the question: how to add GSP-support in Eclipse Oxygen? Is there any new plugin for it?

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is still under development and won't be finally released until June 2017. It sounds like GSP has not yet been tested with Oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

Support for the old grails IDE plugin has arrived, the update sites required:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookmarks>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/46/dev/update" selected="true" name="AJDT"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen" selected="true" name="Eclipse EPP 4.7 (Oxygen)"/>
   <site url="jar:file:/local/path/somewhere/springsource-tool-suite-3.6.4.RELEASE-e4.5-updatesite.zip!/" selected="true" name="GGTS"/>
   <site url="http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.7/" selected="true" name="GrEclipse"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest" selected="true" name="Oomph Latest Milestone"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen" selected="true" name="Oxygen"/>
   <site url="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7" selected="true" name="The Eclipse Project Updates"/>
</bookmarks>
```